# Get a percentage of users from the past 30 days from the current date

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date, datetime

I am on laravel mysql and I want a percentage and number of how many new users have been created or left in the past 30 days.
For example, if there are 3 users before 30 days and 2 new users have been created between 30 days so, according to my calculation it should be ((2-3)/3) *100 = -33.33. I don't know how to get the right percentage. and also if the left users are more then before 30 days users, then it should be shown in red color. I don't know how to differentiate between positive percentages and negative percentages.

I have atteched the screenshort of what i actully want.
[image]

I tried this code but i am not 100% sure about the output.

```
        $currentDate = Carbon::now();
        $startDate = now()->subDays(30)->startOfDay();


        $startDate = Carbon::now()->subDays(30);
        $totalUsers = User::count();
        $createdUsers = User::where('created_at', '>=', $startDate)->count();

        $number = (($createdUsers - $totalUsers) / $totalUsers+1)  * 100;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried walking through this with your example numbers, but I do not understand how an increase of users can result in a negative growth value (-33.33%).
The only ways I can imagine you wanting a negative value are:

- Either **your total number of users has dropped** since 30 days ago, in which case your logic needs to allow for this. Counting the total number of users now, and also counting the subset of those created in the past month, is completely blind to any users that might have existed previously, but don't now.
- Or **you want to compare the number of new users in this period with the number of new users in a previous period**, in which case, looking at the total seems entirely irrelevant, and you should be looking at the number of users created *between 60 and 30 days ago*, and *30 days ago and now*.

Perhaps you do just want to look at the total number of users, relative to 30 days ago. In which case, here's a walk-through, and suggested code that might achieve that.

Say you had 3 users before, and an additional 2 users in the past 30 days.
I assume for that, the absolute number of new users you want is 2, and the percentage you want is 66.67%, because 3 + 2 = 5, and 5 is ~1.67 times your original number, or an increase of ~66.67%.

```
$currentDate = Carbon::now();
$startDate = now()->subDays(30)->startOfDay();

$startDate = Carbon::now()->subDays(30);
$totalUsers = User::count(); // 5
$createdUsers = User::where('created_at', '>=', $startDate)->count(); // 2

$number = (($createdUsers - $totalUsers) / $totalUsers+1)  * 100;
// ((2 - 5) / 5 + 1) * 100
// ((-3) / 5 + 1) * 100
// (-3/5 + 1) * 100
// (2/5) * 100
// 40
```

so your code would result in 40, which is seemingly not the desired result.

Instead, you could do:

```
$numberOfUsersNow = User::count(); // 5
$numberOfNewUsers = User::where('created_at', '>=', $startDate)->count(); // 2
$numberOfUsersPreviously = $numberOfUsersNow - $numberOfNewUsers; // 3

$percentageIncreaseInNumberOfUsers = $numberOfNewUsers / $numberOfUsersPreviously * 100; // 66.666666666667
```

Comment: Thank you Simon Mayer for your time and code.

Comment: @RonakPanchal: note that the answer that you selected, posted by Govind, was not created by that poster but was ChatGPT-generated crap. Don't trust it, and for the benefit of future visitors, please un-accept it. Again, it is not to be trusted as ChatGPT creates answers that sound correct but often contain glaring mistakes. And the poster who posted it themself has no ability to differentiate between the two. They're just plagiarizing what the AI generated.

Comment: @RonakPanchal: note also that *this* answer by SimonMayer looks to be a more correct answer, and in my opinion, the one that you should select as "correct".

Comment: @RonakPanchal please accept SimonMayer's answer, I am not a developer I am a content writer so I am not sure about my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the percentage and number of new users created or left in the past 30 days, you can use the following steps:

Get the count of users before 30 days:

```
$usersBefore30Days = User::whereDate('created_at', '<', now()->subDays(30))->count();
```

Get the count of new users created in the past 30 days:

```
$newUsers = User::whereDate('created_at', '>=', now()->subDays(30))->count();
```

Calculate the percentage difference:

```
$percentageDifference = (($newUsers - $usersBefore30Days) / $usersBefore30Days) * 100;
```

Determine the color based on the percentage difference:

```
$color = $percentageDifference < 0 ? 'red' : 'green';
```

You can then use the $percentageDifference and $color variables to display the result accordingly in your Laravel view.

Here's an example of how you can implement this in a Laravel view:

```
<div>
    @if ($percentageDifference < 0)
        <span style="color: red;">{{ $percentageDifference }}%</span>
    @else
        <span style="color: green;">{{ $percentageDifference }}%</span>
    @endif
    <span>{{ $newUsers }} new users</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Sidenote, you can do a 1-liner like `<span style="color: {{ $color }};">{{ $percentageDifference }}%</span>`; no need for the `@if` and repeating the `<span>` element.

Comment: More ChatGPT-generated crap

Comment: I hadn't looked at this deeply until now, but the calculation is flawed for the reasons stated in my answer.

Comment: re: coloring, @TimLewis's comment appears to be an improvement and makes sense, based on the code provided, but defining the colors here seems like it could become unwieldy. Perhaps even better would be to define CSS classes for positive, negative (and perhaps even zero) values, and keeping the styling out of the HTML. So `<span class="{{ $className }}">{{ $percentageDifference }}%</span>`